# Let $p$ be an odd prime such that $p \equiv 2\ \text{(mod 3)}$. Find $|E|$ where $E=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{F}_p \times \mathbb{F}_p | y^2 = x^3 +1\}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime such that $p \equiv 2\ \text{(mod 3)}$. Let $\mathbb{F}_p$  be the field with $p$ elements. Consider the subset $E$ of $\mathbb{F}_p \times \mathbb{F}_p$ given by $$E=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{F}_p \times \mathbb{F}_p \mid y^2 = x^3 +1\}.$$ Which of the  following are true?

1. $E$ has atleast two elements.
2. $E$ has atmost $2p$ elements.
3. $E$ can have $p^2$ elements.
4. $E$ has atleast $2p$ elements.

My attempt: Take $p=5$. Then I found $\{(0,4), (2,3), (2,2), (0,1), (3,2), (3,1), (2,0)\}$ are the solutions of the given equation.

So, I found 1. is true, 2. is true, 4. is false. But I have no idea for 3.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: For 3. consider how many elements are in $\mathbb{F}_p \times \mathbb{F}_p$ in total? Note that your example proves that 4. is not always true but it doesn't prove that 1. and 2. are always true.

Comment: for $p=5$, I get $\{\{0,1\},\{0,4\},\{2,2\},\{2,3\},\{4,0\}\}$. I guess you know that $(0,1)$ is always a solution. How about $(p-1,0)$?

Comment: You can play around a bit here if you'd like by changing what $p$ is: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=uhgczf

Comment: For $p=5$ , $(3,2), (3,1)$ are not solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $|E| = p.$

If $p$ is an odd prime that is $2 \mod 3$ then note that it has a primitive root $w$ such that $w^{1},...,w^{p-1}$ generate the modulo classes $1,...,p-1 \mod p$. Note that if $(h,p-1) = 1$ then $w^{h}$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, in particular $w^{3}$ is also a primitive root modulo $p$. Thus $(w^{a})^3+1 \not \equiv (w^{b})^3+1 \mod p$ for $a \not \equiv b \mod p-1$.

Thus $1^3+1, 2^3+1,...,(p-1)^3+1$ are all distinct modulo $p$, furthermore $\textbf{none}$ of them are $1 \mod p$ as if $h^3+1 \equiv 1 \mod p$ then $h^3\equiv 0 \mod p$. Thus $0^3+1,...,(p-1)^3+1$ are all distinct $\mod p$.

Note that there are $\frac{p+1}{2}$ quadratic residues $\mod p$ where if $j$ is a non-zero quadratic residue then it has two distinct square roots, and $0$ has exactly one square root namely $0$. Thus

$$|E| = 2|\{x: x^{3}+1 \text{ is a quadratic residue mod }p, 0 \leq x \leq p-2\}|+|\{ (0,p-1)\}|$$

$$= 2(\frac{p-1}{2})+1 = p$$

Comment: Note that saying $1^3,2^3,\dots,(p-1)^3$ are distinct *didn't* use the existence of a primitive root in an essential way. Knowing $\mathbb F_p^\times$ is abelian of order coprime to $3$ suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
Let $N\left( y^2-x^3=1 \right) $denote the number of solutions of the equation over a finite field.
then we know
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
   N\left( y^2-x^3=1 \right) &=\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
     a-b=1\\
     a,b\in F_p\\
   \end{array}}{N\left( y^2=a \right) N\left( x^3=b \right)}\\
  &=\sum_{a=0}^{p-1}{N\left( y^2=a \right) N\left( x^3=a-1 \right)}\\
  \end{aligned}
 \end{equation*}

And because $p\equiv 2\left( mod3 \right) ,\left( 3,p-1 \right) =1$, we know $\left( \frac{a}{p} \right) _3=1$ for all $a \in F_p$,$\left( \frac{a}{p} \right) _3$ is the 3-power residues.

so $$\sum_{a=0}^{p-1}{N\left( y^2=a \right) N\left( x^3=a-1 \right)}=\sum_{a=0}^{p-1}{N\left( y^2=a \right)}$$,From the relevant knowledge of quadratic residue,$\sum_{a=0}^{p-1}{N\left( y^2=a \right)}=p$

we can get the $|E|=p$